# Error: Types don't match between the anchor and the recursive part , recursive cte for decimal datatype

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, common-table-expression

I have something as the below

```
declare @t table (id int identity,Price decimal(6,2))
insert into @t
    select 17.5 union all 
    select 10.34 union all 
    select 2.0 union all 
    select 34.5
```

Now if I write a query as below

```
;with cte(id, price) as 
(
    select id, price
    from @t 
    union all
    select cte.id, cte.price + t.price
    from cte 
        join @t t
           on cte.id < t.id
)
select *
from @t
```

I am getting the below error at runtime:

> Types don't match between the anchor
> and the recursive part....

I even tried the same after typecasting(to decimal) but with same result ....

However, if I typecast to int it works... but that should not be the case (:

Comment: This should not be marked as a duplicate, as it deals with the Decimal data type and not varchar like the alleged duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fix:

```
;with cte(id,price) as 
(
    Select id, price from @t 
    Union all
    Select cte.id, cast(cte.price + t.price as decimal(6,2))
    From cte 
    Join @t t
    On cte.id < t.id
)
Select * from @t
```

Explanation:

The expression `cte.price + t.price` will return the type that is not necessarily decimal(6,2), can return decimal(5,2). So it cannot union those two values after that.

Comment: That's a good explanation and I'd consider this a bug even, as the DBMS is told to merely add something to the cte.price, sees that an intermediate result would fit into a decimal with a lower precision, "optimzes" the original precision away, and then complains that the reduced precision doesn't suffice. (And if we decide to change the table someday and allow for a greater precision that even breaks the already tried and tested query.) Sadly, this is still the case in the current version (SQL Server 2019).

Comment: @ThorstenKettner - this answer is wrong. `decimal(6,2)` + `decimal(6,2)` returns a result of `decimal(7,2)` - which is fair enough as otherwise `9999.99 + 9999.99` would overflow  - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks - so `decimal(7,2)`  is still different than `decimal(6,2)` and still gives the error but `decimal(5,2)` isn't involved anywhere

Answer (score 0):

The issue with `decimal` is that when you multiply/divide/add/subtract then [most of the time the resultant expression has a different scale and precision than the input expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16&redirectedfrom=MSDN#remarks).

In this case the result of `decimal(6,2)` + `decimal(6,2)` is a column of datatype `decimal(7,2)`

This is because `decimal(7,2)` is enough to fit the worst case precision/scale requirements (`9999.99` + `9999.99`).

Plugging in the `s` and `p` values into the formula in the above link gives

```
SELECT greatest(2, 2) + greatest(6 - 2, 6 - 2) + 1 AS [ResultPrecision],
       greatest(2, 2)                              AS [ResultScale]
```

You can explicitly cast the column in the recursive branch to that of the anchor datatype **if you are confident that you will never in fact overflow with your data** (as in [Alex's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6289734/73226))

Or choose an appropriate precision and scale suitable for both the anchor and recursive branches and explicitly cast both branches to that.

```
;with cte(id, price) as 
(
select id, CAST(price AS decimal(10,2))
from @t 
union all
select cte.id, CAST(cte.price + t.price AS decimal(10,2))
from cte 
    join @t t
        on cte.id < t.id
)
select *
from @t
```

Alternatively you can cast the anchor branch to `decimal(38,6)`

When you add/divide/multiply or subtract two `decimal(38,6)` you end up with a `decimal(38,6)` so this also solves the mismatched datatype error.

```
;with cte(id, price) as 
(
    select id, CAST(price AS decimal(38,6))
    from @t 
    union all
    select cte.id, cte.price + t.price
    from cte 
        join @t t
           on cte.id < t.id
)
select *
from @t
```

The reason for this equilibrium here is due to the fact that the precision cannot go any higher than `38` combined with the rule

> The scale is set to 6 if it's greater than 6 and if the integral part
> is greater than 32.